# Rerendering of one sibling component due to data update in other sibling component in Next JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, prisma, trpc.io

I have a Next JS app where I am using Layout feature in the `_app.tsx` component. I am showing a sidebar in the layout which is getting populated from an api call(get request).

Now I have another api call (update request) on button click in `Index.tsx` file. This update request changes data in the layout's sidebar component.

Here are my code snippets

`_app.tsx`

```
import { type AppType } from "next/app";
import { type Session } from "next-auth";
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";

import { trpc } from "../utils/trpc";

import "../styles/globals.css";
import MainLayout from "../components/layouts/MainLayout";

const MyApp: AppType<{ session: Session | null }> = ({
  Component,
  pageProps: { session, ...pageProps },
}) => {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={session}>
      <MainLayout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </MainLayout>
    </SessionProvider>
  );
};

export default trpc.withTRPC(MyApp);
```

`MainLayout.tsx`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

import { trpc } from "../../utils/trpc";

import { AiOutlineOrderedList } from "react-icons/ai";
import { BsCartCheckFill, BsGraphUp, BsSuitHeartFill } from "react-icons/bs";
import { IoRefresh } from "react-icons/io5";
import { IoMdArrowBack } from "react-icons/io";
import { MdModeEditOutline } from "react-icons/md";

import { Space_Grotesk } from "@next/font/google";

import { SelectedData } from "@prisma/client";

const spaceGrotesk = Space_Grotesk({
  weight: "500",
  subsets: ["latin"],
});

type MainLayoutProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

type DefaultItemProps = {
  setItemMode: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<"default" | "add" | "show">>;
  data: SelectedData[]
};

type ItemProps = {
  setItemMode: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<"default" | "add" | "show">>;
};

const MainLayout = ({ children }: MainLayoutProps) => {
  const [itemMode, setItemMode] = useState<"default" | "add" | "show">(
    "default"
  );
  const pathname = useRouter().pathname.split("/")[1];

  const { data: selectedData } = trpc?.selectedData?.getAllData?.useQuery();

  return (
    <div className={`flex h-screen flex-row gap-0 ${spaceGrotesk.className}`}>
      <div className="flex min-h-full w-20 flex-col items-center justify-between bg-white py-6">
        <div className="rounded-full bg-[#3f3d56] p-3">
          <BsSuitHeartFill size="1.3rem" className="text-[#f9a109]" />
        </div>

        <div className="flex flex-col gap-12">
          <Link href="/">
            <span
              className={`tooltip rounded-full p-3 ${
                pathname === "" && "text-[#f9a109]"
              }`}
              id="Items"
            >
              <span className="hidden">Items</span>
              <AiOutlineOrderedList size="1.3rem" />
            </span>
          </Link>
          <Link href="/history">
            <span
              className={`tooltip rounded-full p-3 ${
                pathname === "history" && "text-[#f9a109]"
              }`}
              id="History"
            >
              <span className="hidden">History</span>
              <IoRefresh size="1.3rem" />
            </span>
          </Link>
          <Link href="/statistics">
            <span
              className={`tooltip rounded-full p-3 ${
                pathname === "statistics" && "text-[#f9a109]"
              }`}
              id="Statistics"
            >
              <span className="hidden">Statistics</span>
              <BsGraphUp size="1.3rem" />
            </span>
          </Link>
        </div>

        <div className="relative rounded-full bg-[#f9a109] p-3">
          <span className="absolute top-[-6px] right-[-6px] flex h-5 w-5 items-center justify-center rounded-lg bg-[#eb5757] p-2 text-white">
            3
          </span>
          <BsCartCheckFill size="1.3rem" className="text-white" />
        </div>
      </div>

      {children}

      {itemMode === "default" && <DefaultItem setItemMode={setItemMode} data={selectedData!} />}
      {itemMode === "add" && <AddItem setItemMode={setItemMode} />}
      {itemMode === "show" && <ShowItem setItemMode={setItemMode} />}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MainLayout;

const DefaultItem = ({ setItemMode, data }: DefaultItemProps) => {
  return (
    <div className="flex w-[20%] flex-col justify-between bg-white">
      <div className="flex h-full flex-col items-center gap-5 bg-[#fff0de] py-6 px-5">
        <div className="flex items-center justify-center gap-7 rounded-lg bg-[#80485b] px-6">
          <img
            className="relative right-1 h-32 w-12 -translate-y-4 rotate-[-20deg]"
            src="/kissclipart-cola-bottle-png-clipart-fizzy-drinks-beer-bottle-853f3ea787dad24a-removebg-preview.png"
            alt="bear-bottle"
          />

          <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center gap-3">
            <span className="text-white">Didn't find what you need?</span>
            <button
              onClick={() => setItemMode("add")}
              className="w-fit rounded-xl bg-white px-4 py-2 text-[#80485b]"
            >
              Add Item
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="flex w-full items-center justify-between">
          <span className="text-xl">Shopping List</span>
          <MdModeEditOutline size="1.3rem" />
        </div>

        <div className="flex flex-col gap-5">
          <div className="flex max-h-[440px] flex-col gap-4 overflow-y-auto px-1">
            {data?.map((item) => (
              <div className="flex flex-col gap-2" key={item.id}>
                <span className="text-[14px] text-slate-500">
                  {item.name}
                </span>
                <div className="flex flex-col gap-1">
                  {item?.items.map((item: string, i: number) => (
                    <div key={i} className="flex items-center justify-between">
                      <span className="min-w-[179px] max-w-[180px] truncate">
                        {item}
                      </span>
                      <button className="rounded-lg border-2 border-[#f9a109] px-2 py-1 text-[#f9a109]">
                        3 pcs
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  ))}
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="my-5 flex items-center justify-center rounded-xl  border-2 border-[#f9a109]">
        <input
          className="w-full bg-transparent px-4 outline-none"
          placeholder="Enter a name"
          type="text"
          title="name"
        />
        <button className="rounded-lg bg-[#f9a109] px-5 py-3 text-white">
          Save
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const AddItem = ({ setItemMode }: ItemProps) => {
  return (
    <div className="flex min-h-full w-[20%] flex-col justify-between gap-7 bg-white py-5 px-4">
      <div className="flex flex-col gap-5">
        <h3 className="text-2xl">Add a new item</h3>

        <div className="flex flex-col gap-5">
          <div className="flex flex-col gap-1">
            <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
            <input
              className="rounded-lg border-2 border-stone-500 px-4 py-2 outline-none hover:border-[#f9a109] focus:border-[#f9a109]"
              placeholder="Enter a name"
              type="text"
              id="name"
            />
          </div>

          <div className="flex flex-col gap-1">
            <label htmlFor="note">Note (optional)</label>
            <textarea
              className="rounded-lg border-2 border-stone-500 px-4 py-2 outline-none hover:border-[#f9a109] focus:border-[#f9a109]"
              placeholder="Enter a note"
              rows={4}
              id="note"
            />
          </div>

          <div className="">
            <label htmlFor="images">Images</label>
            <input
              className="w-full rounded-lg border-2 border-stone-500 px-4 py-2 outline-none hover:border-[#f9a109] focus:border-[#f9a109]"
              placeholder="Enter an url"
              type="text"
              id="images"
            />
          </div>

          <div className="flex flex-col gap-1">
            <label htmlFor="category">Category</label>
            <input
              className="rounded-lg border-2 border-stone-500 px-4 py-2 outline-none hover:border-[#f9a109] focus:border-[#f9a109]"
              placeholder="Enter a category"
              type="text"
              id="category"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
        <button
          onClick={() => setItemMode("default")}
          className="rounded-lg px-5 py-3"
        >
          Cancel
        </button>

        <button
          onClick={() => setItemMode("show")}
          className="rounded-lg bg-[#f9a109] px-5 py-3 text-white"
        >
          Save
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const ShowItem = ({ setItemMode }: ItemProps) => {
  return (
    <div className="flex min-h-full w-[20%] flex-col justify-between gap-7 bg-white py-5 px-4">
      <div className="flex flex-col gap-5">
        <button className="flex items-center gap-2 px-3 text-[#f9a109]">
          <IoMdArrowBack size="1.3rem" /> back
        </button>

        <div className="flex flex-col gap-5">
          <div className="flex items-center justify-center">
            <img
              className="h-44 rounded-lg"
              src="/avocado-slices-500x500.jpg"
              alt="item-image"
            />
          </div>

          <div className="flex flex-col gap-1">
            <h6 className="text-gray-500">Name</h6>
            <span className="text-lg">Avocado</span>
          </div>

          <div className="flex flex-col gap-1">
            <h6 className="text-gray-500">Category</h6>
            <span className="text-lg">Fruits and Vegetable</span>
          </div>

          <div className="flex flex-col gap-1">
            <h6 className="text-gray-500">Note</h6>
            <span className="text-lg">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nihil
              soluta culpa, fugit aut, ea corrupti rem molestias dolor dolorem
              odit voluptate, facilis fuga reprehenderit commodi perspiciatis
              optio aperiam recusandae aliquam.
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
        <button
          onClick={() => setItemMode("add")}
          className="rounded-lg px-5 py-3"
        >
          Back
        </button>

        <button
          onClick={() => setItemMode("default")}
          className="rounded-lg bg-[#f9a109] px-5 py-3 text-white"
        >
          Save
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

`Index.tsx`

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { GetServerSideProps, type NextPage } from "next";
import Head from "next/head";
// import Link from "next/link";
// import { signIn, signOut, useSession } from "next-auth/react";

import { type Data, PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

import { Dancing_Script } from "@next/font/google";

import { IoAddOutline } from "react-icons/io5";
import { AiOutlineSearch } from "react-icons/ai";
import Overlay from "../components/common/Feedback/Overlay";

import { trpc } from "../utils/trpc";

type HomePageProps = {
  datas: Data[];
};

const dancingScript = Dancing_Script({
  weight: "700",
  subsets: ["latin"],
});

const Home: NextPage<HomePageProps> = ({ datas }) => {
  const [filteringList, setFilteringList] = useState(datas);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const mutation = trpc.selectedData.addItemToShopingList.useMutation();

  const searchHandler = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
    const filteredList = datas.map((list) => {
      return {
        ...list,
        items: list.items.filter((item) =>
          item.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase())
        ),
      };
    });
    setFilteringList(filteredList);
  };

  const addItemToShopingList = async (
    item: string,
    name: string,
    id: string
  ) => {
    if (mutation.error) {
      return alert("Something went wrong");
    }
    mutation.mutate({
      id,
      name,
      item,
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Shoppingify | Items</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create-t3-app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <Overlay isShowing={false} />

      <div className="flex min-h-full flex-1 flex-col gap-12 bg-[#fafafe] px-16 py-8">
        <div className="flex w-full items-center gap-40">
          <h1 className="text-4xl">
            <span className={`${dancingScript.className} text-[#f9a109]`}>
              Shoppingify
            </span>{" "}
            allows you take your shopping list wherever you go
          </h1>

          <div className="relative flex items-start rounded-lg shadow-lg">
            <AiOutlineSearch className="absolute top-4 left-3" size="1.5rem" />
            <input
              className="rounded-lg px-12 py-4 outline-none"
              onChange={searchHandler}
              value={search}
              type="search"
              name="search"
              placeholder="Search Items"
              id="search"
            />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="flex max-h-[600px] flex-col gap-10 overflow-y-auto py-2">
          {filteringList?.map((list) => (
            <div key={list?.id} className="flex flex-col gap-7">
              <h3 className="text-2xl">{list?.name}</h3>
              <div className="flex flex-wrap items-center justify-center gap-5 space-x-3">
                {list?.items.map((item: string, idx: number) => (
                  <div
                    className="flex items-center justify-center gap-3 rounded-md px-4 py-2 shadow-md"
                    key={idx}
                  >
                    {item}{" "}
                    <button
                      onClick={() =>
                        addItemToShopingList(item, list?.name, list?.id)
                      }
                      title="add-item"
                    >
                      <IoAddOutline size="1.3rem" />
                    </button>
                  </div>
                ))}
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  const prisma = new PrismaClient();
  const datas = await prisma.data.findMany();

  return { props: { datas } };
};
```

So my question is how can I update the layout's sidebar data after data is updated from `Index.tsx` file.

Comment: Data that is fetched (and changed) can be kept in the browser! To explain, use a React Context or some React State to keep track of the data that comes in from server. Any changes to it, should be made in React, via state setters. When updating the data, you want to instantly see the change (setting the state in react), and a side-effect should be pushing the updated data back to the server. This proposed "solution" does have caveats, but they are the best ones to have in a situation like this. Please respond if you have any questions or if I did not make sense in any part of this comment!

Comment: You mean i just need to use context for updating the data, right?

Comment: Yes. An alternative would be `useState`, but it's up to you and the needs of the application.

Comment: You should look up "invalidateQueries" and "setCacheData" on the react-query docs. This is what trpc uses and is very likely what you need here.

Comment: something like `trpc.selectedData.getAllData.setData()` in the `onSuccess` callback of your mutation. Or this https://trpc.io/docs/useContext#query-invalidation

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to update the `Home` component to contain a state representing the `datas` prop and any added data the user adds when using the shopping list. The `filteringList` state can use this "fluctuating" state instead of using the prop passed in. The extra state would look something like this:

*Note*: Anywhere you use the prop `datas`, you'd instead use `fluctuatingList`.

```
const Home: NextPage<HomePageProps> = ({ datas }) => {
  const [fluctuatingList, setFluctuatingList] = useState(datas);
  // You can still set the filtered list to initially be set with `datas`
  const [filteringList, setFilteringList] = useState(datas);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const mutation = trpc.selectedData.addItemToShopingList.useMutation();
...
```

Then when updating the search, map using the `fluctuatingList`:

```
  const searchHandler = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
    // Check the line below
    const filteredList = fluctuatingList.map((list) => {
      return {
        ...list,
        items: list.items.filter((item) =>
          item.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase())
        ),
      };
    });
    setFilteringList(filteredList);
  };
```

Now, I'll be honest, I did not take the time to digest your snippets to give a usable solution, but guessing what `@prisma/client`'s `Data` type is, I am going to assume it looks like an object with the three parameters in this function:

```
  const addItemToShopingList = async (
    item: string,
    name: string,
    id: string
  ) => {
    if (mutation.error) {
      return alert("Something went wrong");
    }

    // Pulling this into a `const` for reuse
    const newData = {
      id,
      name,
      item,
    };

    // Here is where we mutate the data, I am guessing through some API call
    // We also want to set the fluctuating state here:
    setFluctuatingList((prevList) => ([ ...Array.from(prevList), newData ]));
    mutation.mutate(newData);
  };
```

Thumbs me up if you think its a good answer!